# Counter implemented using Client Server in Erlang OTP

Tags: erlang-otp

I am trying to implement a counter using the Erlang/OTP Client Server. In the following code I can set a count to count up from, but the `incr()` function does not work. Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

---

```
-module(counter2).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start/1, stop/0, incr/0, get_count/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, terminate/2, handle_info/2]).

% Client Functions
start(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, counter2}, counter2, [Args], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(conter2, stop).

incr() ->
    io:format("incr called: ~n"),
    gen_server:call(counter2, {incr, self()}).

get_count() ->
    gen_server:call(counter2, {get_count, self()}).

% Callback functions
init(Args) ->
    Count = Args,
    {ok, Count}.

handle_call({incr, Pid}, _From, Count) ->
    {NewCount, Reply} = incr(Count, Pid),
    io:format("In incr Reply: ~p~n", [Reply]),
    {reply, Reply, NewCount};
handle_call({get_count, Pid}, _From, Count) ->
    {NewCount, Reply} = get_count(Count, Pid),
    {reply, Reply, NewCount}.

handle_cast(stop, Count) ->
    {stop, normal, Count}.

handle_info(_Msg, Count) ->
    {noreply, Count}.

terminate(_Reason, _Count) ->
    ok.

incr(Count, _Pid) ->
    io:format("In incr:~n"),
    NewCount = (Count + 1),
    {ok, NewCount}.

get_count(Count, _Pid) ->
    {ok, Count}.
```

The counter function `incr()` should count up from a set value and return the value to the client request.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections Steve. I have now modified the file so that i should only count up from zero to a given value. But in the code, the if construct does not work to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you're calling the `start/1` function, so I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
counter2:start(42).
```

The `start/1` function passes its arguments to `init/1` by putting them in a list argument to `gen_server:start_link/4`:

```
gen_server:start_link({local, counter2}, counter2, [Args], []).
```

This means that for our example, the `init/1` function is getting `Args` as `[42]`, which is stored directly as the server state, and is not what you intended. In an erlang shell if you first start your server and then use the `sys:get_state/1` to examine its state, you'll see that it's not storing the number:

```
1> counter2:start(42).
{ok,<0.161.0>}
2> sys:get_state(counter2).
"*"
```

The state is `"*"` which is the same as `[42]` since 42 is the ASCII value for the asterisk character.

You can fix this by changing the `start/1` function to pass `Args` directly:

```
gen_server:start_link({local, counter2}, counter2, Args, []).
```

If we recompile and try our experiment in the erlang shell again, now the state is correct:

```
3> c("counter2").
counter2
4> counter2:start(42).
{ok,<0.179.0>}
5> sys:get_state(counter2).
42
```

Now let's call `incr/0`:

```
6> counter2:incr().
incr called: 
In incr: 
In incr Reply: 43
43
```

It seems to work, but unfortunately calling `incr/0` again crashes the server:

```
7> counter2:incr().
incr called: 
In incr: 
=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Aug-2023::09:19:09.992451 ===
** Generic server counter2 terminating
```

This is because the `handle_call/3` function mishandles the reply from the `incr/2` function:

```
handle_call({incr, Pid}, _From, Count) ->
    {NewCount, Reply} = incr(Count, Pid),
```

The `NewCount` and `Reply` members of the tuple receiving the result are switched; they should be:

```
handle_call({incr, Pid}, _From, Count) ->
    {Reply, NewCount} = incr(Count, Pid),
```

With this change, and if we fix the `io:format` call following this code to print `NewCount`, then multiple increments work correctly, and our state is correct:

```
8> counter2:incr().
incr called: 
In incr: 
In incr Reply: 43
ok
9> counter2:incr().
incr called: 
In incr: 
In incr Reply: 44
ok
10> sys:get_state(counter2).
44
```

The `counter2:get_count/0` function also has the same problem with the reversed tuple members:

```
handle_call({get_count, Pid}, _From, Count) ->
    {NewCount, Reply} = get_count(Count, Pid),
```

Fixing that allows `counter2:get_count/0` to work correctly as well, returning the expected value (same as what `sys:get_state/1` shows):

```
11> counter2:get_count().
44
```

Lastly, the `counter2:stop/0` function doesn't work either, due to a typo in the registered process name (`conter2` instead of `counter2`). It should be:

```
stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(counter2, stop).
```